# how to get percentage of two numbers and calculate from a percentage

Tags: c#, .net, math, percentage

I am developing a application that need to calculate percentage from two numbers. dotnet have some method for do this? i like to write this calculate by myself. but i don't good in mathematics unfortunately.
really, how to get percentage in mathematics? for example i have 10000 request in my application, and 400 request of them are for special part of my application. how to calculate what percent of request are request for a part of my application?
and how to calculate reverse, for example, i know 5 percent of users like my special post, how can calculate number of users that like that post?
Thank you and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Requests: 400 / 10000 = 0.04 (4%) Posts: 60 users (for example) - 100%; X - 5%; X = 60 * 5% / 100% = 3 users

Comment: Explanation https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/proportions.html

Answer (score 12):

> dotnet have some method for do this?

Since it's just arithmetic, every programming language has this.  Generally, the calculation would be...

If you want to find "What percent of `Y` is `X`?", such as "What percent of 100 is 50?", then you divide `X` by `Y`:

```
var percent = x / y;
```

or:

```
50 / 100 = 0.5
```

**Note**, however, that in programming languages you *do* have to be concerned with data types.  In C# for example, if `X` and `Y` are `int`s then the result will be `0`, *not* `0.5`.  This is because an `int` divided by an `int` is also an `int`.

In that case you'd need to cast them to something like a `double` to get sub-integer precision:

```
var percent = (double)x / (double)y;
```

---

> how can calculate number of users that like that post?

That would just be the reverse.  Consider the values that you *do* know:

- I have 100 users.
- 0.05 of the total like the post.

Then the number of users who like the post is the percentage times the total:

```
var numberOfLikes = percentOfLikes * totalUsers;
```

or:

```
0.05 * 100 = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

> This is a practical explanation with words, since you're probably not into theory that much

**Looking for a percentage**

Write 400 out of 10'000 as a fraction, because that is what you look for: 400/10'000 = 0.04 in one (since 10'000 is all you got, hence one). That would mean 0.04*100 in 100, or 4%.

Equivalent statements:

```
    400/10000
    0.04
    4%
```

Any given number x in a population of y is (x/y)*100%.

**Given a percentage**

Note how the percent sign has two zeros in it, it literally means "per hundred". So if you do *100%, it's actually the same as multiplying by one, just another notation.

The other way around, again, think in words. Let's say 50 is 20% of someting. That means there is another 80% to the total; 50*(100/20) = 250.

Equivalent statements:

```
    50 = 20%*x
    50 = 0.2*x
    250 = x
```